# Prove the following by contradiction: for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $9 \nmid (n^2 + 3)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understand that I need to derive *false* from $\neg(9 \nmid (n^2 + 3))$, or $9 \mid n^2 + 3$. To do this, I attempted to say $n^2 + 3 = 9k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then I tried something like $3 = -n^2 = -3(k - 1)$, but $-3 \mid 3$. That doesn't contradict the statement.

I think that I'm missing something very fundamental here. Any clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: There are just two cases you have to distinguish, mainly $n=3k$ and $n=3k\pm 1$. Show, that in both cases $9\nmid n^2+3$.

Comment: proof by contradiction - Hint: $9 ~| ~(n^2 + 3) ~\implies ~3 ~| ~n^2.$  Question: if $~3 ~| ~n^2,~$ does this imply that $~3 ~| ~n$?  If it does imply that, *so what*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $9 \mid (n^2+3) $ then $n^2 = 9m - 3$. So $3 \mid n^2$, and in turn $3 \mid n$ and there is an integer $k$ so that $n = 3k$. Substitute this back into the equation: $(3k)^2 = 9m-3$. So $9k^2=9m-3$ and this means $9 \mid 3$, impossible. Hence $9\nmid (n^2+3)$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:   The remainder of dividing a number by 9 can be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8. When squaring those numbers, all these remainders become  0,1,4,0,7,7,0,4 or 1, respectively.  When adding 3, these remainders become, respectively, 3,4,7,3,1,1,3,7,4. None of these remainders is zero, so indeed $n^2+3$ is never a multiple of 9.
EDIT: To learn more about it:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

If you assume $\forall n, 9 \mid n^2 + 3$ then you can easily get a contradiction. A forall is like a machine that prints out facts, so we use it to print out a version with $n=2$ say. This gives us the assumption $9 \mid 2^2 + 3$ i.e $9 \mid 7$. That gives us our proof of false.